Additive Homomorphic MAC
I've started learning about homomorphic MACs [1] but most of the work is on fully-homomorphic MACs. Is there a more simple additive homomorphic MAC that is secure and easy to implement?
[1] https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/194.pdf
